# Grails GSP - Display different textfields dependant on locale

Tags: grails, if-statement, locale, gsp

I'm having an issue trying to display a different g:textfield dependant on the users locale using Grails 2.4.3.

I've found that to bypass an issue raised in Grails 2.4.3 I have to set the a variable on my gsp page:

```
<g:set var="lang" value="${session.'org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver.LOCALE'}" />
```

I can display ${lang} correctly and see the correct value on screen.

I have to display a different textfield dependant on the locale value so I assumed I could use the following but it doesn't work?

```
<g:if test="${lang.equals('de')}">
    German Textfield
</g:if>
```

I have tried the lang.equals and lang == de which I've shown here with each de and en

```
<g:elseif test="${lang == 'en'}">
    English Textfield
</g:elseif>

<g:else>
    no language support
</g:else>
```

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this:

```
<g:if test="${lang == Locale.GERMAN}">
...
```

I would recommend you to get the current locale like this:

```
<%@ page import="org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils" %>

<g:set var="lang" value="${RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request)}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Locale is not a language. It holds both country and language. Refer to [specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html).

```
<g:set var="locale" value="${RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request)}" />
<g:if test="${locale == Locale.GERMAN}">German Textfield</g:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ page import="org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils" %>
<g:set var="lang" value="${RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request)}" />
...

<g:if test="${lang.getLanguage() == 'ru'}">
```